# Why is the text in the files I am concatenating in Powershell coming out altered?

Tags: powershell, nlp, corpus

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, I'm not much of a programmer.

I am using PowerShell to concatenate all of the files within a folder into a single larger file, however when I do this, the text itself comes out 'corrupted'.

I have a folder of Ancient Greek texts that all end with a `.tess` extension, these files come from https://github.com/cltk/grc_text_tesserae/tree/master/texts (I'm not sure how this extension works, but it opens fine in Notepad).
I used:

```
Get-Content *.tess | Set-Content greekcorpus.tess
```

However, the text would come out scrambled. For example:

```
Σιδὼν ἐπὶ θαλάττῃ πόλις
```

Comes out as:

```
Î£Î¹Î´Ï‰Ì€Î½ ÎµÌ“Ï€Î¹Ì€ Î¸Î±Î»Î±ÌÏ„Ï„Î·Í… Ï€Î¿ÌÎ»Î¹Ï"
```

Anyone know what could be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This would be a problem if you were using powershell 5.1 where `Get-Content` defaults to ANSI encoding. try `Get-Content thefiles* -Encoding utf8 | Set-Content mergedfiles -Encoding utf8`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1701026)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do the work :

```
Get-Content *.tess -Encoding UTF8
```